# R Scripts should contain same certain syntax

Tags: r, customization, rstudio

I'm using R/R-Studio. Is there a possibility to automatically include always the same lines of code/comments when creating a new script?

Comment: "lines of code/comments" - do you mean load certain packages every time? Look into [.Rprofile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300769)

Comment: Yes, for example. And adding the same comments at the start of the script every time.

Comment: Good question: How about author, created, ...?

Comment: I would create a `template.R` and open it for new files, then `Save as`.

Comment: Same question, with no answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35158708

Comment: Thanks a lot, I go with the "snippet" solution, described under the following link provided by @zx8754

Comment: There seems to be [nothing around](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200821846-Default-header-author-info-etc-)

Comment: I just posted a solution using snippets [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35158708/how-to-set-default-template-for-new-r-files-in-rstudio). I was not aware of @zx8754's comment.